# postgres what information is stored for a connection

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

Looking to find more connection information that PostgreSQL stores.

I did find these queries:

```
SELECT datname, numbackends 
FROM pg_stat_database
WHERE numbackends > 0
ORDER BY numbackends DESC, datname

SELECT datname, COUNT(*) AS numbackends
FROM pg_stat_activity 
GROUP BY datname HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

But I'm looking to find out what script(s) or IP's are connecting or have current connections to PostgreSQL, is there anything that captures this information?

NOTE: Turning Logging on is not the solution I'm looking for, more of a on the fly report I can filter by the script or IP connecting to the database

Postgres version 7.4

Comment: any reason you are still on 7.4?

Comment: Yes, it's not my choice and the person who wants this employs me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of the connected clients is also recorded in pg_stat_activity, just as the currently running statement (if any)

```
SELECT usename, 
       application_name, -- only valid for 9.x 
       client_addr, 
       backend_start,
       query_start,
       current_query
FROM pg_stat_activity
```

Comment: Sry forgot to mention Postgres version 7.4 Running SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
LIMIT 1 only returns these two fields query_start and current_query from your list

Comment: @Phill Pafford: you should immediately upgrade to a supported version of Postgres. 7.x has been de-supported for some time now. The last supported version is 8.2.

Comment: Would love to but it's not my choice

Comment: I know that feeling. Perhaps you should point your client at http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/